# Box plot legend

Tags: spss

I am using box plot to visualise some data, and I want to add some information in graph like this [boxplot-with-legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yaAC.jpg). Does anyone know how can I add this in SPSS?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this isn't really feasible. BTW, in SPSS Statistics box plots, as with Tukey's original versions, the whiskers don't span from min to max, but the smallest to the largest cases that are outside the box but still inside the two "fences". The fences are set at 1.5 IQRs below and above the box edges.